# Spring Boot Configuration File Location From Tomcat

Tags: spring-boot, tomcat

I'm trying to setup backend application so it gets different configuration files depending on env.

On dev env I would like to load default application.yml from classpath. This should be the case when I'm running the app via: `mvn spring-boot:run` or `java -jar ./target/myapp.war`

But when this app is running on Tomcat it should load application.yml from server specific file e.g. `/etc/apps/myapp/application.yml` (not default one from classpath) because server has different mongodb credentials etc...

I don't want to use `profiles` because this mean I need to put server credentials in project on github in application.yml. I just want that this is known by server administrator and developer don't know anything about it.

Is there any way how can I tell this application inside tomcat to load different configuration file.

In this Tomcat I have other applications that are using spring boot so I need some solution that is independent. Setting globally `spring.config.location` is not the case because all apps will load this one file.

Answer (score 1):

You can use `@PropertyResource` annotation with context xml.

NOTE: `ignoreResourceNotFound` will help not throw exception when file not found, say for Dev env.

```
@Configuration
  @PropertySources({
    @PropertySource("classpath:application.properties"),
    @PropertySource(value = "file:${config.file}", ignoreResourceNotFound=true)
    })
public class AppConfig {
    //...
}
```

**/META-INF/context.xml**

```
<Context>
    <Parameter name="config.file" value="/yourpath/application.properties"/>
</Context>
```

If you don't want to save path in context.xml inside your project, there are other ways to define application level context depending on your tomcat version. Please [refer](https://tomcat.apache.org/tomcat-9.0-doc/config/context.html) here for details for tomcat 9.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to read properties from **external location** then write `bootstrap.yml` in your application and delete `application.yml`.

bootstrap.yml:

```
spring:
  config:
    location: file:/home/external/properties/location/
    name: application
  profiles:
    active: dev
```

file location: `/home/external/properties/location/`

suppose you need dev and prod environment.Then keep this 3 properties file in this location.

```
application.yml

application-dev.yml

application-prod.yml
```

Spring boot read `application.yml` properties first. If set active profile `dev` in `bootstrap.yml` then `application.yml` value **overwrite** by `application-dev.yml`.

**Or you can use config server**

Look at [this](https://dzone.com/articles/using-spring-config-server)